# special case (!) of blank page in pdf issue in report builder /SSRS

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I am aware that the blank page issue in pdf-exports from Report Builder / SSRS has been addressed numerous times here and elsewhere. However, I am faced with a particular version of the problem on which I have not been able to find more information.

I use Report Builder 3.0 to generate form letters (based on the follwing approach:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519552.aspx) 
Initially an extra blank page appeared as the last page. I then applied the usual solutions (i.e. made sure my margins, text boxes etc. where ok , set consumecontainerwhitespace to true) and this seemed to solve the problem.

My report contains a parameter allowing users to (de)select addressees. If and only if exactly one addressee is chosen, the problem reappears (irrespective of which adressee is chosen). 
Does anyone have a clue how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe take a look at the page break properties on your grouping, especially if you have something grouped by that addressee. Try setting it to just "between each instance"

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to react. I did as you suggested but the problem persists.

Comment: The issue only happens on export-to-pdf? Can you replicate it from a physical printer?

Comment: Haven't actually printed it, put the blank page definitely shows up in the Print Preview layout in report builder. (Won't be able to access my report till Thursday BTW, so I won't be able to test your suggestions immediately.

Comment: UPDATE: can confirm that the issue is NOT limited to pdf-export.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a big tablix with only one cell and add a row group on address (if this is the case) then try adding a rectangle in this cell and in this rectangle try adding the tablix you use. Set the tablix dimensions as long as your report page, if you have margins try making these margins 0 as PDF has a shrink over-sized pages option when printing.

You can set the page break options for the big tablix as between groups. I had such a situation and this solution helped me.